# How Can I Print Values and Index Numbers of an ArrayList without a Loop?

Tags: java, arraylist

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BasicArraylists0 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();

        arrayList.add(-113);
        arrayList.add(-113);

        System.out.println(arrayList); // prints [-113, -113]
    }
}
```

I want to code so that it prints values, -113s in this case, and index without any brackets without using any for or while loop?

For example, I would like to print something like

"Slot 0 has a -113"
"Slot 1 has a -113"
and so on.

Okay, here is the question:

"Create an ArrayList that can hold Integers. Add ten copies of the number -113 to the ArrayList. Then display the contents of the ArrayList on the screen.

Do not use a loop. Also, do not use any variable for the index; you must use literal numbers to refer to each slot."

Comment: Short answer is you can't without writing code to format it the way you want, and iteration over a collection requires a loop. If you're using Java 8 you could use the lambda capabilities but that's just syntactic sugar that would hide a loop.  The loop is still there.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're looking for in the output? Are you looking for something like `0 -113, 1 -113`? You will have to iterate through the array to do proper formatting etc.

Comment: @user1875195 Yes. For example, I would like to print something like "Slot 0 has a -113", "Slot 1 has a -113", and so on.

Comment: @Jiwon you will have to iterate through the array. Is there a reason why you can't loop through the array?

Comment: @user1875195 How do I iterate through the array? The reason why is because the question I am trying to solve says not to use any loop..

Comment: Btw to create a list that holds integers, do `ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: @4castle How do I use ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(); if I want to print index numbers?

Comment: @4castle was pointing out that you should fix that line, since `ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();` will **accept any Object, not just Integers**. As for printing index numbers, I don't see where in your program requirements at the bottom it actually requires that you do this. All it asks you to print are the contents of the array. Am I missing something here? As for it asking you not to use a loop, this is a pretty vague program requirement. Most things you can do use a (hidden) for loop. Pretty much everything else uses some other form of iteration.

Comment: Using `ArrayList<Integer>` is using a feature called generics. It won't effect your ability to print index numbers, it will only help with specifying the data type of the elements in the ArrayList. @JarrodRoberson That's not a duplicate of this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any way to solve this without some form of iteration. The best way would be to use a `for` loop, but alternatively you could use Java 8's Stream API to loop without explicitly using a loop.

```
IntStream.range(0, arrayList.size())
         .forEach(i -> System.out.println("Slot "+i+" has a "+arrayList.get(i));
```

If you know the size of the `ArrayList`, then I suppose you can just copy-pasta the whole thing:

```
System.out.println("Slot 0 has a "+arrayList.get(0));
System.out.println("Slot 1 has a "+arrayList.get(1));
System.out.println("Slot 2 has a "+arrayList.get(2));
System.out.println("Slot 3 has a "+arrayList.get(3));
System.out.println("Slot 4 has a "+arrayList.get(4));
System.out.println("Slot 5 has a "+arrayList.get(5));
System.out.println("Slot 6 has a "+arrayList.get(6));
System.out.println("Slot 7 has a "+arrayList.get(7));
System.out.println("Slot 8 has a "+arrayList.get(8));
System.out.println("Slot 9 has a "+arrayList.get(9));
```

Comment: Thank you, 4castle!

Comment: <!-- language: lang-java -->
  List<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList() {
   public String toString(){
    ListIterator itr = this.listIterator();
    StringBuffer r = new StringBuffer();
    boolean hasNext = itr.hasNext();
    while (hasNext){
     int index = itr.nextIndex();
     Object o = itr.next();
     if (o == this)
      r.append("<this>");
     else
      r.append("Slot " + index + " has a " + o);
     hasNext = itr.hasNext();
     if (hasNext)
      r.append("\n");
    }return r.toString();
   }
  };
  System.out.println(arrayList.toString());

Answer (score 0):

Let me understand your question, you want to print an entire ArrayList without loops? If so, you can use the following code:

```
arrayList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

This uses the new Java 8 lamda's feature.

Comment: Streams actually can't be used like that here. They want the index to be in the output, and Streams don't have a concept of an index. It would have to be mapped first to a `Map<Integer, Object>`, but that's not efficient.

Comment: Oh, I didn't read the id part, my bad. If he need to print the id, I think he should use at least 1 loop.